# Spring integration imap adapter exception

Tags: spring, spring-integration, geronimo

I am trying to use spring itegration imap inbound adapter,but i am getting this exception every time i run my application

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.imap.IMAPSSLStore.        <init>(javax.mail.Session, javax.mail.URLName)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1812)
    at javax.mail.Session.getService(Session.java:799)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:586)
    at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:548)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openSession(AbstractMailReceiver.java:207)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:226)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver.waitForNewMessages(ImapMailReceiver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$IdleTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:220)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter$ReceivingTask.run(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:190)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My spring configuration is this

```
<int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
      store-uri="imaps://username:password1@imap.gmail.com:993/inbox"
      java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
      channel="receiveChannel"
      should-delete-messages="false"
      should-mark-messages-as-read="false"
      auto-startup="true"/>


<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
  <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
  <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
  <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
  <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
 </util:properties>
```

Anyone any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are using an incompatible (probably old) JavaMail version. What version of geronimo are you using?

Spring integration is built/tested with `javax.mail` 1.5.2 (and the com.`sun.mail` implementation).

Comment: You are right.I removed geronimo dependency from my pom.Now it is working.Thanks.

Comment: I see you are new to Stack Overflow - it is customary to mark the answer as 'accepted' to help other people searching for similar questions/answers.